# Tkinter Toplevel() positioning without static geometry

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.5, toplevel

Im using `Toplevel()` for popup windows and I want the popup to be displayed to the right of the mouse when it comes up. I found how to do this but only by specifying the geometry of the window. How can I control where the window comes up without specifying the size. I want the window to be the size it needs to be for whatever data is is going to display.

This is what im using right now:

```
helpwindow = Toplevel()
helpwindow.overrideredirect(1)
helpwindow.geometry("662x390+{0}+{1}".format(event.x_root - 1, event.y_root - 12))
```

How can I put only the format settings in the window geometry? Or is their a better way?

Comment: `helpwindow.geometry("+{0}+{1}".format(...))` - ie. `helpwindow.geometry("+200+200")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"+{}+{}"` without size

```
helpwindow.geometry("+{}+{}".format(event.x_root - 1, event.y_root - 12))
```

ie. moving window :)

```
import tkinter as tk

def move():
    global pos_x

    helpwindow.geometry("+{}+200".format(pos_x))
    pos_x += 10

    root.after(100, move)

root = tk.Tk()

pos_x = 0    
helpwindow = tk.Toplevel()
move()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried that but I deleted the + before {0} thinking it was used like in a print('text' + variable). Knew it was something simple. Thanks